# Swedish characters giving potentially dangerous request.form value error on Ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am calling a controller function from Ajax in my view

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetSelectedItemsForRoleId","User")",
    data: { optionLabel: '@CommonResource.DropdownNoValueText', optionValue: null, selectedValue: null, filterValue: 0 },
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
        var departmentDropdown = $('#RoleId').data("DropDownList");
        departmentDropdown.setDataSource(result);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('XMLHttpRequest ' + XMLHttpRequest);
        alert('textStatus ' + textStatus);
        alert('errorThrown ' + errorThrown);
        //some stuff on failure
    },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    async: false
});
```

**CommonResource.DropdownNoValueText** is `-Välj-`

I get the following error in failure block :

**potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client**

My controller signature looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetSelectedItemsForRoleId(string optionLabel, string optionValue, string selectedValue, int filterValue)
```

I tried to put `ValidateInput` annotation above this function and set it to false.
After doing that the string appears as `-V&#228;lj-`.
What is the cause of this and how can I derive the original text i.e. `-Välj-`?

**Update**:
I have further tried with two things:

1. I replaced `@CommonResource.DropdownNoValueText` directly with `-Välj-`. Now I don't get any error.(But this isn't the correct solution as this won't resolve the lingustic feature).
2. I replaced `DropdownNoValueText` in `CommonResource` with something else like **eee** which also does not give error.(But even this isn't the solution).

Comment: Related, possibly duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: This is because the ModelBinder is encountering some characters which it thinks are hostile, usually `<` or `>` in a XSS attempt.

Comment: I guess the issue is because of ä character.

Comment: @Tomalak : I can't place validateFalse in Pages as it would lead to incorrect or harmful input data. I am applying this only on dropdown and this string value is hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with both Swedish and Spanish characters.
We used method `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` which encoded characters from strings and caused ampersand followed by hash symbol:

```
puntuaci&#243;n
```

which in turn caused .NET's security reaction (error returned).

Solution was to change default encoder used by classes `HtmlUtility` to not use default encoder (`HtmlEncoder`) but rather `AntiXssEncoder` which doesn't encode characters such as special Swedish or Spanish characters because they are harmless (cannot be used in XSS attack).

After this, Swedish/Spanish characters aren't encoded and consequently `&#` string is avoided too, so .NET's security reaction (error) is avoided.
This change is in config file and probably has global effect:

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder"/>
```

*Just to add some information about avoiding cause of situation - unsuccessful attempt of resolving this issue was to use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` instead of `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` which changed string to :*

```
puntuaci&amp;#243;n
```

*so that `&amp;` was used instead of `&#` which avoided problem but caused other unwanted side-effects.*

Comment: Further experiences with this issue - problem again happened with Russian language, so `Server.HtmlEncode` in `.cshtml` was used and `Server.Html.Decode` was used in controller method, along with `[ValidateInput(false)]` as attribute of controller method.